# Using existing key from dict in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i am using pandas to aggregate my dataset and i got stuck calculating the fields.

Here is my code

```py
df = self.df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(
            calc1=(x.vol).sum()/(x.hours).sum() if (x.hours).sum() > 0 else 0,
            calc2=(x.vol_2).sum()/calc1 if calc1 > 0 else 0,
        )))
```

in the third line i am trying to leverage the first element from the dict but it keeps returning an error

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'calc1'

Is there a way to use the previously created calculated field or is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: thanks - wasn't aware of these articles, will get familiarized with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to create a dictionary through `dict()` and reference entries in a dictionary that was not yet completed. As a quick solution:

```py
def my_func(x):
    d = dict(calc1=(x.vol).sum()/(x.hours).sum() if (x.hours).sum() > 0 else 0)
    d['calc2'] = (x.vol_2).sum()/d['calc1'] if d['calc1'] > 0 else 0
    return pd.Series(d)

df = self.df.groupby('year').apply(my_func)
```